# how to handle angular ngIf on boolean condition

Tags: angular

I have a google map on my project, I have made control position for the button like this:

```js
map: any;
mapReady(event: any) {
  this.map = event;
  this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(document.getElementById('open'));
  this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(document.getElementById('Settings'));
}
```

I have buttons like this:

```html
<button mat-mini-fab class="shadow bg-light" style="margin-top: 10px !important;" [hidden]="hideOpen" id="open"
    (click)="openbtn()" *ngIf="open_btn">
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
</button>

<button mat-mini-fab class="shadow bg-info" style="margin-top: 10px !important; margin-left: 30px;"
    [hidden]="hideSettings" id="Settings" *ngIf="!open_btn">
    <mat-icon class="text-white">4k</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Initially, the first button will be visible, second is hidden, when I click on the first button I should display the second button.

I have tried this:

```js
open_btn: boolean = true;
close_btn: boolean = false;
openbtn(){
  this.open_btn = false;
  this.close_btn = true;
}
```

Comment: Either use `*ngIf` or `[hidden]` attribute. If you're using both, then both need to adjusted to show the element. So in the event handler you also need to include `hideSettings = false`.

Comment: @MichaelD    I have tried by removing the [hidden] on the both buttons, but it didn't worked.

Comment: If you remove the [hidden] then it should work - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-if-buttons?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

As already @yash told, If you remove the [hidden] property it works just fine.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-if-buttons-erufv9